# Propagate entries in django/python logging

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am looking for a practical explanation of the difference between having `propagate` be true or false. Here is the current logger I have:

```
LOGGING = {
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)d@%(funcName)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'formatter': 'default'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'default'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'app': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

If I set `propagate` to False, what would happen in the above case? Would it still send messages to `mail_admins`, or would it only use the first item? What exactly would be the difference between the two settings, beyond just what it says in the django docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/.